# Sharepoint 2010 BDC: Connecting to Oracle an using assembly fails

Tags: oracle, sharepoint-2010, bdc

I'm trying to make a BDC connection in Sharepoint 2010 to an Oracle Database using an assembly. When unit testing the assembly, it works perfectly, but when using it in the BDC, I get the following exception: 'The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client'

The rest of the BDC model works fine; if I return dummy objects instead of actual Oracle results from my assembly, they show up as they should.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea why it wouldn't work, but I circumvented the problem by using a WCF service for the BDC connection instead of an assembly.

Suspicions regarding the original cause go towards a 32/64 bit conflict (although compiling everything to 64 bit didn't resolve it) or perhaps a conflict between 64 bit ODP.NET and Win 2k8 (["The 64 bit ODP.NET for Oracle 11 does not work on Win2k8 64 bit."](http://brianhochgurtel.blogspot.com/2010/03/installing-oracle-client-on-64-bit.html))

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of the following:
1. You can connect with another oracle client from the same machine.
2. The Running code and the called assembly has the same bit executable (32\64)

For me the latter was the problem and had to reinstall..